# Pointer to variadic function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I have a simple class `A`, providing a variadic function template. This function uses private data from within `A`, but the function itself is public. The class goes as follows:

```
class A {
public:

    A() :
    _bla("bla: ") {
    }

    template <class T>
    void bar(const T& value) {
        std::cout << _bla << value << std::endl;
    }

    template <class H, class... T>
    void bar(const H& value, const T&... data) {
        std::cout << _bla << value << std::endl;
        bar(data...);
    }

private:
    const std::string _bla;
};
```

In a separate file, named *foo.hpp*, I have a function `foo()`, that should be able to receive and use the function `a.bar()` as an argument:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    
    A a;
    a.bar(1, "two", 3, 4);
    foo(&a.bar);
}
```

I'm not very sure of where to start, but I've tried the following -- which does not work. How can I do it correctly:

```
template <typename... T>
inline void foo(void (bar *)(const T&...)) {
    unsigned int x(0), y(0), z(0);
    bar(x, y, z);
}
```

**Bonus question:** is there a way to call not only:

```
foo(&a.bar);
```

but also call `foo` with `a.bar` bound to some parameters, like:

```
foo(&(a.bar(p1, p2));
```

I can simply add `p1` and `p2` to `foo` definition itself, like in:

```
foo(p1, p2, &a.bar);
```

but it would be *semantically* better to my purpose if I could add these parameters before.

Comment: Why the `enable_if` mess? You can just overload it as `void bar() {}`.

Comment: By the way, there's no need to use `enable_if` to tell whether the argument pack is empty. Just have one template overload for `(H,T...)` and one overload with no arguments that does nothing.

Comment: `foo` accepts a function, but `a.bar` is not a function. It is a template. Templates have no addresses. There are functions `a.bar<int>`, `a.bar<double, char>` etc; which one do you want to pass to `foo`? Also, how do you distinguish `a.bar(p1, p2)` as a function bound to some parameters and `a.bar(p1, p2)` as a function fully applied to all parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot pass the address of a function template without instantiating it, because that is treated as a whole overload set (no matter whether the template is variadic or not). You can, however, wrap it in a generic functor:

```
struct bar_caller
{
    template<typename... Ts>
    void operator () (A& a, Ts&&... args)
    {
        a.bar(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
};
```

And then let your function `foo()` be defined as follows:

```
template<typename F>
inline void foo(A& a, F f) {
    unsigned int x(0), y(0), z(0);
    f(a, x, y, z);
}
```

So your function call in `main()` would become:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.bar(1, "two", 3, 4);
    foo(a, bar_caller());
}
```

Unfortunately, at the moment there is no way in C++ to easily wrap an overload set in a functor without defining a separate class - as done above for `bar_caller`.

**EDIT:**

If you do not want to pass an `A` object directly to `foo()`, you can still let your `bar_caller` encapsulate a reference to the `A` object on which the function `bar()` has to be called (just take care of object lifetime, so that you won't be making that reference dangling):

```
struct bar_caller
{
    bar_caller(A& a_) : a(a_) { }

    template<typename... Ts>
    void operator () (Ts&&... args)
    {
        a.bar(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }

    A& a;
};
```

You could then rewrite `foo()` and `main()` as follows:

```
template<typename F>
inline void foo(F f) {
    unsigned int x(0), y(0), z(0);
    f(x, y, z);
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.bar(1, "two", 3, 4);
    foo(bar_caller(a));
}
```

Comment: +1 Andy, thanks very much for your answer! In the real case, I have a class that extends other classes, and includes `A`, a smaller class in my program. If I get to `# include` my outer class in `A` -- which is actually included in the outer class --, I guess the mess I already have would become an epic spaghetti ^^ I don't really mind the *extra parameters*, I can add them to `foo` definition, but I really wouldn't like to have to pass `A` -- my outer class -- to `foo`. Is there any possible work around?

Comment: Andy, I actually have `A` as the *outer function*, and `bar` is a function available from inheritance. I was, until now, passing variables as references to `foo`, so that `foo` would *fill up* the variables, and I would call `bar` in `A` itself, with the values I've retrieved from `foo`. I'm just adding a bit of context to make it clearer. I'm checking your edit right now.

Comment: Perfect solution! I guess I'll be able to do exactly what I want now! Just one last question, what exactly is the meaning of the double reference in `void operator()(Ts&&... args){}`?